# Access rights of undefined access member variable (neither public nor private)

Tags: c++, class, member, access-specifier

What happens to a member variable in C++ if you don't define the access rights?

For instance, in the following code:

```
class Base {
  int myQuestion;
  public:
    int myPublic;
  private:
    int myPrivate;
}
```

Who has access to `myQuestion`?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4962942/560648

Answer (score 5):

If you use the keyword `class`, access defaults to `private`. If you use `struct` it defaults to `public`.

That's pretty much the only difference between the two keywords.

The only other difference is when you inherit, `class` defaults to private inheritance, `struct` to public inheritance.

Comment: It is the only difference

Comment: [Both types are classes; C++ does not have structs](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/28a9cdb264a25723). Discuss use of the _keywords_ `class` and `struct` instead, to avoid spreading misconceptions.

Comment: @king_nak "It is the only difference" - you forget the difference in default inheritance. There are *two* differences between `class` and `struct`; default access and default inheritance type.

Answer (score 1):

In a `class`, it is `private`. In a `struct`, it is `public`.

Answer (score 1):

In `class` it is `private`, in `struct` it is `public` by default.